# Exclude file extentions for Java based compiler?

Tags: java, parsing, file-extension, lexical-analysis, javacc

I usually find a workaround for problems, but this time I cannot seem to find one.

I am making a compiler for a self-designed language using JavaCC. Before I simply used System.in to read files, so this way I know my compiler can use any text-based file of any extension.

This project must ONLY open files with a custom extension (.bait). From my research, there are plenty of ways in Java to get a file's extension, but they all require a full path. My compiler is supposed to run from any place in the user's disk through a terminal (CMD), so I do not think Java's options are useful.

The question: How can I filter the file extension of a given file that the compiler rejects the source if it's not .bait?

The original code I use is pretty simple:

```
hook analizador = new hook (System.in);
analizador.RunLexer();
```

'hook' being the class and RunLexer() is a method for lexical analysis. The code allows any text-based code to be analyzed. For the extention rule I thought of using *.bait regular expresion as in:

```
hook analizador = new hook (new FileInputStream("*.bait"));
analizador.codigo();
```

and

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("*.bait");
hook analizador = new hook (input);
```

with no luck, so far. Can anybody guide me with this? An explanation of the answer will be gladly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thanks to sepp2k and MeetTitan.

System.in was not an option, so instead the filename (used as argument) can be used for all the verifications needed:

```
String arc = args[0];
if(arc.endsWith(".bait")){ //checks file extention
    File src = new File(arc); //created just to use exists()
    if(src.exists()){
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(arc); //used instead of System.in
        hook analizador = new hook(fr);
    } else System.out.println("File not found");
} else System.out.println("Invalid filetype");
```

As for the way to use the program, using terminal (CMD)

```
java hook file.bait
```

This code doesn't let the user run .bait files out of the hook directory as intended, so it's safe even if there are several copies of the file in different locations.

Hope it can be of any use to someone, and thank you again, sepp2k and MeetTitan!

Comment: "As far as I've researched, there are plenty ways in java to get the extention of a file, but they all need a full path." Which ways did you find and what makes you think that they need a full path?

Comment: Mostly using .lastIndexOf() and .substring(). They use Strings to validate the path, but I'm not handling paths at all. So, if I use System.in for a File ie, I would need to create a String, then get the path of the file with another method (getCanonicalPath(), perhaps?) and then validate? The problem is that it didn't work either, so I'm missing something still

Comment: Neither `lastIndexOf` nor `substring` require a full path, relative paths work fine (I assume that by "full" you mean "absolute" - otherwise I don't know what you mean). "So, if I use System.in for a File" What does that mean? I thought you *were* using `System.in`, but now you want to read from a file (instead of `System.in`). If you're still reading from `System.in` and only redirecting from a file, you won't have access to the file name, so you can't validate it.

Comment: I meant: I used System.in as in the first bloc of code. Through CMD, the way to use the compiler with a file is by `java hook < file.bait`, there I noticed that any text file works for the lexical analysis (And I just recently found that it works for the Sintax(?) analysis too). The next thing to do then is to make it work only with .bait, so I assumed that System.in would only help to read the file's content. In my mind, changing the System.in for any object that manages files and let me acces the content of the file itself could be used for both extention validation and content analysis

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you call your application as `java hook < file.bait`, you **can't** check the file name. You'd have to actually take the file name as an argument (i.e. `java hook file.bait`) and then actually read from that file instead of `System.in`.

Comment: Ok, that answers some questions indeed, thank you! So, using the file name as an argument I should be able to get the path to check the extention. For that, Im guessing, I would need the third block of code or something similar. Then, checking the java.IO optiones should be my next move, did I get it right?

Comment: A file name *is* a (relative) path. If you take the file name as an argument, all you need to do to check the extension is `filename.endsWith(".bait")` (or any of the other options that were already mentioned) where `String filename = args[0];` (make sure that the user provided at least one argument before you do this or you might get an index-out-of-bounds exception). Then the next step would be to create an input stream to read the file, yes.

Comment: Hey, just to update. I tried pretty much all the ideas you and @MeetTitan gave me and I got it working now, so thank you very much! I'll edit the question to add the answer so this "thread" can be closed.

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase always.

Comment: Then: `new FileInputStream("*.bait");` simply cant work. **WILDCARDS** are a feature of the underlying file system. Java doesnt know that you want `*` to match any file name! It will just look for a file name "*.bait", which of course doesnt exist. Honestly: i have the impression that you are massively overburdening yourself. What you are asking for sounds like a real challenge for an experienced programmer, but yet you have many holes in your knowledge. I would really commend that you spent quite a bit of time learning the basics before continuing with your task.

Comment: "WILDCARDS are a feature of the underlying file system" No, they're not. They're a feature of the shell. If they were somehow a feature of the filesystem, using "*.bait" would work fine because `FileInputStream` would just pass it to `fopen`, which would pass it to the file system, which would understand it if it were file system feature. Of course, using a pattern that could match arbitrarily many files to refer to a single file is nonsensical in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do something like this?

```
//this method takes a String and returns a substring containing the characters between the last occurrence of '.' and the end of the String
//For example, getExtension("test/your.file.bait"); will return "bait".
public static String getExtension(String fileNameOrPath) {
    return fileNameOrPath.substring(fileNameOrPath.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
}

//this method compares equality of "bait" and the returned extension from our other method
public static boolean isBait(String fileNameOrPath) {
     return "bait".equals(getExtension(fileNameOrPath));
}
```

You can use `isBait(String)` on any path, relative or absolute, or a filename.

You could also simply leverage `String.endsWith(String)`.
Like so:

```
public static boolean isBait(String str) {
    return str.endsWith(".bait");
}
```

**EDIT**
To get a listing of all files in a folder with a specific extension, you'd use a `FilenameFilter` with `File.listFiles()`

Like so:

```
File dir = new File("path/to/folder");
File[] baitFiles = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".bait");
    }
});
```

**EDIT** to recurse over EVERY subfolder and only get certain files:

```
public static List<File> recurseGetBait(File dir) { //need method for recursion
    List<File> baitFilesList = new ArrayList<>(); //make a new ArrayList that we will populate and return
    File[] baitFiles = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { //get all bait files with previously shown snippet
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".bait");
        }
    });
    for(File baitFile : baitFiles) {
        baitFilesList.add(baitFile); //add every file from baitFiles to baitFilesList
    }
    String[] dirs = file.list(new FilenameFilter() { //get all subfolders of current folder
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
        }
    });
    for(File dir : dirs) { //iterate over all subfolders
        List<File> returned = recursiveGetBait(dir); //run this same method on this subfolder (which will recurse until there are no sub folders)
        baitFilesList.addAll(returned); // add all of the previously returned bait files to baitFilesList so we populate and return
    }
    return baitFilesList; //either returns our list to the previous recurse or returns the fully built list to our original caller
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt that make necesary to write in the code the path to the file? The way the users will use the compiler is through the command `java hook < file.bait`, the file being in the same folder as hook.java is. So I need a way to make the compiler recieve all the files, but only work with those ending with .bait. I like the code provided, tbh, can you think in a way to get the path? Or am I trying to do the things in a complicated way?

Comment: @Jetto, I believe understand your question more. Unless you mean how to get current directory?. Please check my edit.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't imagined I could use the directory itself for that validation. Is very interesting, although I'm a little concerned about the instalation directory of the compiler. Can I use this same method to get the path to the .java or .class files? ie finding the directory of hook.java to get the instalation directory, and then use it for `dir`

Comment: You could recurse over subdirectories in your given root folder. I'll write up an edit for you soon with code.

Comment: I see... I think I can definitely implement this for a better user experience. Perhaps as a way to allow a dedicated .bait files, or even better, a data folder for the compiler and a files folder for user generated code.